# Data.Binary encodeFile does not seem to be thread safe - corrupted file?

Tags: multithreading, haskell

I'm trying to replicate a situation where a binary file was essentially corrupted with a filesize of `0` in a real world application via [encodeFile](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary-0.10.0.0/docs/Data-Binary.html#v:encodeFile), this occurred after a hard reboot.

Although I've not been able to replicate this behavior exactly, I have gotten it to replicate a corrupted(?) file with code below.

When we first run it (some text is garbled due to multiple threads printing):

```
"New valid file written"
Example "hmm" [0]
"Testing..."
"Donenn"oo
tt  een#no~ouGugHghCh I bDby-ytSteTesAs
R
CTCa~al#lllSSttaacckk  ((ffrroomm  HHaassCCaallllStS#at~caGkcH)kC:)I
:D 
-  Fe IreNrrIorSroH,r- ,5c ~ac#la
llelde #da~ tGa HtsC rIscDr/-cMS/aTMiAanRi.Tnh~.s#h:s5:35:31:51 5i ni nm amiani:nM:aMiani
n
"d"ideiien#ig~n.Gg.H..C..I..D..-..S."T.
Command "cabal v2-repl app" exited unexpectedly
```

After a few runs eventually we get an error of:

```
*** Exception: not enough bytes
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at src/Main.hs:53:15 in main:Main
```

**What is the cause of this error? Is it just the case that `encodeFile` is not safe when used via multiple threads (which is kind of odd as there is no mention of threads on https://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary-0.10.0.0/docs/Data-Binary.html).**

---

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}
module Main where

import System.PosixCompat.Files
import System.Process
import System.Process.Internals
import System.Posix.Signals
import System.Posix.Process
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Monad
import Data.Binary
import GHC.Generics (Generic)
import Control.Exception

data Example = Example String [Int] deriving (Generic, Show)
instance Binary Example

main :: IO ()
main = do
  checkFile
  encodeFile "output.txt" $ Example "hmm" [0]
  checkFile
  print "New valid file written"
  decodeFileOrFail "output.txt" >>= \case
      Right v@(Example s z) -> print v
      Left (e,e') -> do
            error $ e'
            rip
  print "Testing..."
  forM_ [1..3] (const $ forkIO $ catch (do
                     checkFile
                     somethingIO
                     checkFile) (\e -> do
                                            print (e :: SomeException)
                                            rip
                                        )
    )
  print "Done"

checkFile :: IO ()
checkFile = do
  fileExist "output.txt" >>= \case
    True -> do
      x <- getFileSize "output.txt" 
      if x == 0 then
        rip
      else
        pure ()
      decodeFileOrFail "output.txt" >>= \case
        Right (Example s z) -> pure ()
        Left (e,e') -> do
              error $ e'
              rip
    False -> pure ()

rip :: IO ()
rip = do
  print "dieing......."
  getProcessID >>= signalProcess sigKILL

somethingIO :: IO ()
somethingIO = do
  let v = 10 :: Int
  decodeFileOrFail "output.txt" >>= \case
    Right (Example s z) -> encodeFile "output.txt" $ z ++ [v]
    Left (e,e') -> do
          error $ e'
          rip

getFileSize :: String -> IO Int
getFileSize path = getFileStatus path >>= return . fromIntegral . fileSize
```

With a cabal file of:

```
cabal-version: 1.12
name:                HaskellNixCabalStarter
version:             0.1.0.0
author:              HaskellNixCabalStarter
maintainer:          HaskellNixCabalStarter
license:             MIT
build-type:          Simple

executable app
  main-is: Main.hs
  other-modules:
      Paths_HaskellNixCabalStarter
  hs-source-dirs:
      src
  build-depends:
      base >=4.12 && <4.13
    , binary
    , process
    , random
    , unix
    , unix-compat
  default-language: Haskell2010
```

Comment: As a general thumb rule, I would expect no library function which writes to a file to lock said file, unless explicitly documented. If you need to write from several threads, you should be sure to write to different files, or perform the needed locks to avoid race conditions. (In the latter case, be careful with deadlocks as well.) The lock can be performed in-process with a mutex (if no other process is accessing the same file), or at the OS level.

Comment: For your future reference, if a package does **NOT** mention that it is thread-safe, you **MUST** assume it is not thread-safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing particularly mysterious going on here. Reading and writing files simply aren't atomic operations, and this is biting you. If you have one thread writing `output.txt` and another reading `output.txt`, it is completely normal and expected for the reader to occasionally see only part of the file that the writer would eventually produce.

This is not particularly special to the `binary` package, nor even to the language -- this is, to a first approximation, true of nearly every library and language that deals with a filesystem. Guaranteeing atomicity of the appropriate kind is quite hard, indeed; but many, many engineering years have gone into providing this kind of thing for databases, so if that's a need for you, you might consider using one of them.

Alternately, a significantly simpler solution is to have a single thread that is responsible for reading and writing the appropriate file, and to communicate with it via one of Haskell's excellent inter-thread communication tools.

Some OSs do offer an atomic file-rename operation. In such a situation, one could also consider writing to a temporary file, then using an atomic rename to overwrite the filename you actually care about. (Thanks to a commenter who I will leave anonymous because they chose to delete their comment for suggesting this.)